# PyCharm freezing whole computer on Ubuntu

Tags: pycharm, freeze

I am running PyCharm 5 with JDK 8 on a Ubunto 15.10. The problem is that Ubuntu comes with 3 different Python versions and when I am prompted to select the correct interpreter version in PyCharm the whole computer simply freezes. 
Has anyone seen something similar?

Comment: I think it's this issue, you can upvote it to draw more attention: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17968

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question: yes, exactly the same behaviour but with OpenJDK 7 and OpenJDK 8. It freezes the UI; the computer can be accessed eg via SSH so you can kill the PyCharm Java process. I have not been able to investigate further (instead I went back to my old machine, OS X, on which PyCharm is bundled with a Java interpreter).

EDIT with workaround: change the UI Theme in the Settings. In the Settings dialog, under Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance change Theme from 'GTK+' to 'Intellij'. I saved this change, restarted PyCharm, and I am not seeing the freeze. Bug reports on Ubuntu Launchpad and bugs.debian.org suggest problems with GTK+ and OpenJDK, for example:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1510009

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798131

Comment: From the sudden mine stopped freezing and is working nicely. I have NO idea why.

Comment: I am using PyCharm 2017.2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. I changed the theme to IntellJ as above. PyCharm is noticeably faster. Unfortunately, it still intermittently freezes when I try to get to the Find function on the Edit menu.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ev answered, switching to Oracle JDK has so far worked out.

From: https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/

Step 1 – Prerequsities
Before beginning the installation run login shell as the sudo user and update the current packages installed.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Step 2 – Install Java 11 on Ubuntu 18.04
You need to add the following PPA to your Ubuntu system. This PPA contains a package oracle-java11-installer having the Java installation script.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

Then install Java 11 using the script provided in this packages. This script downloads the Java archive from the official site and configures on your system

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer
```

Also, install the following package to configure Java 11 as default Java version on your Ubuntu 18 system.

```
sudo apt install oracle-java11-set-default
```

Here it might throw an error and give instructions to download a jdk_something_tar.gz and `mkdir` and copy it there. Every step is outlined in the terminal error trace.

Also it might ask you to change command to:

```
sudo apt install oracle-java11-set-default-local
```

Step 3 – Verify Java Version
Check the installed Java version on your system using the following command.

```
java -version

java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

so adding `-local` to some commands is requested by the error trace in the terminal.

Then go here:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/switching-boot-jdk.html

Basicaly from the GUI help menu you can:

Switch the Java runtime used to run PyCharm #
On the Help menu, click Find Action, or press Ctrl+Shift+A.

Find and select the Switch Boot JDK action.

Select the desired JDK and click OK.

I was freezing every 10 minutes before but now have been okay all day.

The default JDK was something packaged with Pycharm I believe.