# Running Kafka-python causes whole computer to freeze (ESXi 6.5 VM Virtual Machine Freeze Kernel Panic)

Tags: apache-kafka, virtual-machine, kafka-consumer-api, esxi, kafka-python

I am running Python2.7 with Zookeeper and kafka (0.8.2.1).
I am using the latest Kafka-python client (pip install kafka).

The following is a minimally reproducible example:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = 'myserver.com:my_port'

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic', bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)

print 'about to print messages'

for msg in consumer:

    print msg
```

This prints 'about to print messages', and then the whole VM (Ubuntu Xenial, 16.04 LTS) freezes. I can't even see the cursor inside the VM.

Funny thing is, I am running the exact same Ubuntu Image on one of my other computers (not a VM) and it works.
The VM is running on ESXi 6.5.

This answer [PyCharm freezing whole computer on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824821/pycharm-freezing-whole-computer-on-ubuntu) said it could be openjdk's fault (I don't use pycharm; I execute the code from the terminal), so I switched to Oraclejdk. Didn't solve the problem. I have tried literally everything I can think of and am at my wit's end (ubuntu trusty is downloading, and I am going to try running it on that image and see if that works on the VM).
Any pointers/help appreciated. 
Thank you!

**UPDATE**: If you are getting this issue as well on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) or newer, try a Trusty (14.04) image. **SEEMS** to have solved the problem for me, but probably too soon to tell.

**UPDATE 2** I was wrong. Still doesn't work. Seems like a bug in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known ESX bug. Apparently the reason for this is some invalid op code in certain intel CPUs that gets triggered by the newer versions of Ubuntu (Xenial and above).

I solved it by using Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) instead of 16.04. Hope this helps someone.
Other solutions that didn't work for me (as well as reference links) are below:

launchpad bug-report (edit vmx file a little, didn't work for me)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1630774

vmware-recommended workaround (edit grub file a little didn't work for me)
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2626830#2626830